# Set default sort order to be by 'title' and posts per page to '100'

Tags: categories

Need to change below code to have the default selection to be 'by title' and '100' per page

```
function iknow_posts_sorter() {
    if ( $_GET && ! empty( $_GET ) ) {
        iknow_go_filter();
    }

    $sorterby = ! empty( $_GET['select'] ) ? sanitize_text_field( wp_unslash( $_GET['select'] ) ) : '';


    $sorter_arr = array(
        'newest'   => esc_attr__( 'newest', 'iknow' ),
        'title'    => esc_attr__( 'by title', 'iknow' ),
        /*'comments' => esc_attr__( 'by comments', 'iknow' ),*/
    );

    $posts = ! empty( $_GET['per_page'] ) ? absint( $_GET['per_page'] ) : 'default';

    $posts_arr = array(
        'default' => esc_attr__( 'Default', 'iknow' ),
        '20'      => '20 ' . esc_attr__( 'Per Page', 'iknow' ),
        '50'      => '50 ' . esc_attr__( 'Per Page', 'iknow' ),
        '100'     => '100 ' . esc_attr__( 'Per Page', 'iknow' ),

    );
    ?>
    <form method="get" id="order" class="level-right">
        <div class="level-item">
            <div class="field">
                <div class="control">
                    <div class="select is-small is-primary">
                        <select name="select" class="" onchange="this.form.submit();">
                            <?php
                            foreach ( $sorter_arr as $key => $val ) {
                                echo '<option value="' . esc_attr( $key ) . '" ' . selected( $key, $sorterby, false ) . '>' . esc_attr( $val ) . '</option>';
                            }
                            ?>

                        </select>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="level-item">
            <div class="field">
                <div class="control">
                    <div class="select is-small is-primary">
                        <select name="per_page" class="" onchange="this.form.submit();">
                            <?php
                            foreach ( $posts_arr as $key => $val ) {
                                echo '<option value="' . esc_attr( $key ) . '" ' . selected( $key, $posts, false ) . '>' . esc_attr( $val ) . '</option>';
                            }
                            ?>
                        </select>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>

    <?php

}
```

Answer (score 0):

The current, or selected, values in your code are stored in `$sorterby` and `$posts` variables. The variable values are set by a ternary opertion - a one-line if-statement. The first part is the conditional check, the second part after question mark is the value setting, and after the colon is default value, which is used, if the conditional check fails / is false.

So just match the third part of the ternary operations with any key from the option arrays, `$sorter_arr` and `$posts_arr`, and you should be good to go.

```
$sorterby = ! empty( $_GET['select'] ) ? sanitize_text_field( wp_unslash( $_GET['select'] ) ) : 'title'; // title as default
$posts = ! empty( $_GET['per_page'] ) ? absint( $_GET['per_page'] ) : '100'; // 100 as default
```

**BUT**, do note that you shouldn't make any direct changes to plugin or (parent) theme files (if the code above is from eihter one). Any changes you make will get wiped out next time the plugin or theme is updated. If the code is such that you can copy it to your child theme, then it is safe to edit and won't get overwritten when updates are installed.

Comment: This seems only to change the dropdown defaults to be by 'title' and '100' per page but not actually sorting by those filters.

Comment: @JayCaetano Yes, that is what my example code was supposed to do. Isn't that what you meant with "...change below code to have the default selection to be 'by title' and '100' ..."? If you want to change how the actual filtering is done, then you need to browse the codebase more as it is probably done in some other part of it.

Comment: Yes, I am looking to change the actual filtering. Will go through the codebase. What you provide was helpful though too.

Comment: @JayCaetano You may also want to either edit this question to rephrase it to reflect that intent or close this one and open another one, if you still need help, for example with using filters or actions, after going through the codebase.